# Output date from Inspection Table if ID from inspection table matched Form ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having issues with matching the IDs and then outputting the inspection date to matching ID. The issue is as soon as the if statement reaches an ID that is not matching, it stops even if its in a while loop. Both Ids are from separate sheets, one is called Sling Inv and the other is Form Responses. Form Reponses contains dates that need to be transferred to the cell with the corresponding ID in Sling Inv. I basically want the dates to be transferred over to sheet 1 to the corresponding ID.

```
function dateMatch(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sling Inv");
 var formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses");
 var dataInventory = formSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
 var dataForm = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var date= new Array();


for(n=0;n<dataForm.length;n++){
 var cell = dataForm[n][5]; 
}
Logger.log(cell +"Sling Inv");

for(x=0;x<dataInventory.length;x++){
 var cells = dataInventory[x][17]; 
 date.push([dataInventory[x][2]]);
 Logger.log(cells + date + " form Responses");

 while(x==dataInventory.length){
 if(cell[n]=cells[x]){

 sheet.getRange(3, 15, date.length, date[0].length).setValues(date);          

 }
} 
Logger.log("DATES: "+ date + "END");
```

}
}

| Sling Inspection ID (Sheet 1) | Form ID (Sheet 2) | Date of Inspection(Sheet 2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19255014 | 19255014 | 5/17/2021 |
| 7319005 | 7319005 | 5/17/2021 |
| 15445026 | 15445026 | 5/17/2021 |
| 15445024 | 15445024 | 5/17/2021 |
| 15180013 | 1036052 | 5/17/2021 |
| 1036052 | 15180013 | 5/17/2021 |
| 15445022 | 18242009 | 5/19/2021 |
| 5519004 | 15445022 | 5/19/2021 |
| 18242009 | 7319003 | 5/24/2021 |
| 5272510 | 15445026 | 5/24/2021 |
| 7319003 | 15445022 | 6/1/2021 |
| 19255015 | 18242009 | 6/1/2021 |
| 16161051 | 19925007 | 6/1/2021 |
| 19255009 | 19255004 | 6/2/2021 |
| 19255010 | 16161051 | 6/2/2021 |
| 19255006 | 15180013 | 6/2/2021 |
| 19255004 | 15445024 | 6/7/2021 |
| 19255001 | 18242009 | 6/9/2021 |
| 19255002 | 15445022 | 6/9/2021 |
| 19925007 |  |  |
| 19925006 |  |  |
| 19925012 |  |  |
| 19925011 |  |  |
| 19925013 |  |  |
| 19925009 |  |  |
| 19925008 |  |  |
| 19925010 |  |  |

Comment: My issue is that the if statement causes the program to stop as soon as there is a ID that's not matching, I though it I add a while loop it would loop to the end of the array. Is there a way to have it skip a cell and continue iterating though all the dates. Skipping the ID's that don't match.

Comment: I did not fully understood your goal. Is the table provided your expected output? I would appreciate if you could share a sample sheet. You can also check first the missing `=` in `if(cell[n]=cells[x])`

Comment: This  if statement `if(cell[n]=cells[x]){` does nothing because `cell` is not an array it only contains the last value put into it

Comment: I just shared a sample of the spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't follow links to spreadsheets.  If it's not posted in the code then I don't read it.

Comment: If i understand correctly, You want to write the inspection date to your sheet 1?  by matching the id from sheet1 and sheet2? is that correct?

Comment: And for example, your sheet1 id's are jumbled. the date should be written on the same row where the id is located? and all unmatched id will have a blank date?

Comment: Yes that is correct, there are duplicate IDs and the most recent Date should be outputted to the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a sample code:

```
function dateMatch(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sling Inv");
  var formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var dataInventory = formSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); 
  var dataForm = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var date = new Array();
  Logger.log(dataInventory);
  Logger.log(dataForm);
  var invId = [];
  var invDate = [];

  dataInventory.forEach(data => {
    invId.push(data[0]);
    invDate.push(data[1]);
  });
  invId.reverse();
  invDate.reverse();
  Logger.log(invId);
  Logger.log(invDate);

  dataForm.forEach(slingId => {
    Logger.log(slingId[0]);
    var index = invId.indexOf(slingId[0]);
    Logger.log(index);
    if(index>-1){
      //id found,push the matching date
      date.push([invDate[index]]);
    }else{
      //push empty date
      date.push(['']);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(date);
  sheet.getRange(1,2,date.length, date[0].length).setValues(date);   
  
}
```

**Note:**

- I just followed the sheet structure based on your description table.

### Sample Output:

[image]

### What it does?

1. Get the values of `Sling Inv` and  `Form Responses` sheets using getDisplayValues(). I used this method so that the value obtained will be in string type
2. Separate the ids' and date values obtained in `Form Responses` sheet into 2 different arrays. My main purpose is so that I could use array.indexOf() in checking if `Sling Inv` ids' exist in `Form Responses` ids'
3. I loop each `Sling Inv` ids' and check if it exist in `invId` array. If yes, I will push the matching date. If the id doesn't exist, I will push an empty value.
4. Write the dates obtained to `Sling Inv` sheet

### (Update)

- Since you mentioned that it is possible to have duplicate id's in `Form Responses` sheets. I used `array.reverse()` before using `array.indexOf()` to find the matching id. You need to reverse the date as well when using the return index of `array.indexOf()` to get its matching date.

Comment: Please let me know if you have some issues regarding this solution so I could update/fix accordingly

Comment: There are duplicate IDs such as 15445022. This is because there are part updates, the program logs the dates but only the oldest one. I need the most recent date to be on the sheet such as 6/9 for ID 15445022.

Comment: I updated the code with a simple workaround. Please let me know if you still have further concerns